# Connecting to Coinbase API with Ruby and running into connection issue. Faraday

Tags: ruby, api, coinbase-api, faraday

Attempting to connect to the Coinbase GDAX sandbox API with Ruby.
Currently using Faraday, but HTTParty or Ruby Core API advice is welcomed.

I am having a hard time making post requests and can't seem to tell where I am messing this up.

A laundry list of error's appear but the top one is:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/header.rb:18:in
>   `block in initialize_http_header': undefined method`strip' for
>   1556021965:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Coinbase docs: https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?ruby#signing-a-message

My api call in a nutshell.

```
payload = { 
            "data": "DATA"        
        }

        url = 'https://api-public.sandbox.gdax.com/orders'
        conn = Faraday.new      
        response = conn.post do |req|           
            req.url url
            req.headers['REQ-HEADER-1'] = "FOO",
            req.headers['REQ-HEADER-1'] = "BAR",           
            req.body = payload      
        end

        puts response
```

---

Full Code

```
require 'Faraday' require 'base64' require 'openssl' require 'json'


class foo


    def initialize
        @api_key = '25b1d259417d159443c03ed14eb9ee49'       
        @api_secret = 'trBTZUj4zLfHEBfbQy3+LeLOaAeAbfG/zCqIvzu3RyiKhqf5y85NYqqZi7GUSBCzhryud1pyOs5idibzdOx/tw=='        
        @api_pass = '7zkf0bvr6q4'       
    end         

    def signature(request_path='', body='', timestamp=nil, method='POST')
      body = body.to_json if body.is_a?(Hash)
      timestamp = Time.now.to_i if !timestamp

      what = "#{timestamp}#{method}#{request_path}#{body}";

      # create a sha256 hmac with the secret
      secret = Base64.decode64(@api_secret)
      hash  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', secret, what)
      Base64.strict_encode64(hash)
    end

    def post_buy

        usd = get_usd_available         
        usd = usd / 2       

        payload = { 
            "funds": usd.to_s,
            "product_id": "BTC-USD",
            "side": "buy",
            "type": "market"        
        }

        url = 'https://api-public.sandbox.gdax.com/orders'
        conn = Faraday.new      
        response = conn.post do |req|           
            req.url url
            req.headers['CB-ACCESS-KEY'] = @api_key,
            req.headers['CB-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature( url, payload),
            req.headers['CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = Time.now.to_i,
            req.headers['CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = @passphrase,           
            req.body = payload      
        end

        puts response

    end

end

foo.new.post_buy
```

Comment: have you tried converting TimeStamp to string? and make a request

Comment: when i tried by converting it to string i go this response `{"message"=>"User-Agent header is required."}` & i used HTTPparty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the code at [http/header.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/lib/net/http/header.rb#L18): it calls `strip` on every header, so every header value should be a string.

I think this is the offending line, you are supplying an integer here as the header value:

```
req.headers['CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = Time.now.to_i
```

Converting it to string should fix it:

```
req.headers['CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = Time.now.to_i.to_s
```